# There is some ready/default code to block Internet Explorer 6 or lower versions?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I want show a message to users if they're using IE6 that the browser is outdated in a div. There is something done to do this?

Comment: why show such a message? Probably better to tell them why this browser isn't compatible with your site. On that note, why let them use that browser on your site if it is incompatible? Telling them their browser sucks isn't very helpful.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I want to show a div on the bad-rendered page or in a blank page that the browser is outdated and saying to update the browser to a ner version, displaying some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist ready-to-copypaste scripts for that already. E.g. http://www.ie6nomore.com/

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <div style='border: 1px solid #F7941D; background: #FEEFDA; text-align: center; clear: both; height: 75px; position: relative;'>
    <div style='position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px; font-family: courier new; font-weight: bold;'><a href='#' onclick='javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none"; return false;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-cornerx.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Close this notice'/></a></div>
    <div style='width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; color: black;'>
      <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-warning.jpg' alt='Warning!'/></div>
      <div style='width: 275px; float: left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
        <div style='font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 12px;'>You are using an outdated browser</div>
        <div style='font-size: 12px; margin-top: 6px; line-height: 12px;'>For a better experience using this site, please upgrade to a modern web browser.</div>
      </div>
      <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.firefox.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-firefox.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Firefox 3.5'/></a></div>
      <div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.browserforthebetter.com/download.html' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-ie8.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Internet Explorer 8'/></a></div>
      <div style='width: 73px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/download/' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-safari.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Safari 4'/></a></div>
      <div style='float: left;'><a href='http://www.google.com/chrome' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-chrome.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Google Chrome'/></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with just CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Regular/More CSS Info Here
#wrongbroswer { display:none; }
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
#wrongbroswer { display:; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with code, but this is way more fun:

http://ie6update.com/

It gently encourages....ok, tricks....the user to upgrade their browser in a safe looking manner.  Shifty?  Yes.  But SO much fun to get back at Microsoft for all they do to us web guys...